# NoClassDefFoundError android after change library

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, styleable

In eclipse, I changed library from tibco.jar into tibco_v3.jar. After that I get error: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**: R$styleable....

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't selected private libraries on project properties.

**Go to project in eclipse** and Right click on the project --> **select properties** --> **select java build path** --> **select order and export tab** and select relevant private libraries listed.

Comment: I've checked jar file which my project use. but It cannot solve problem.